# File Upload - I am not able to get the file path for Chrome and Safari browser

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I have created an Image Upload Script in Robot Framework. It is working for the Firefox. But in case of Chrome and Safari browser, it is not able to locate the file path. I have used "Choose File" command. Please Help!

Comment: Please add some more details to your question, especially add your code you wrote

Comment: Code :

Page Should Contain Element | name=upload[] | Choose Files button not get displayed. Sleep | 2
Choose File | name=upload[] | C:\ScriptImages\Images\Injection-icon.png (file path) Sleep | 2

Script fails and generates following error message :

"FAIL ERROR: Command execution failure. Please search the user group at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-users for error details from the log window. The error message is: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable."

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'AutoItLibrary'.

```
Win Wait Active 'The Name of File Upload Dialog'                
Control Set Text            Edit1   'The File Path' 
Control Click           Button2
```

Answer (score 0):

Code :

Page Should Contain Element | name=upload[] | Choose Files button not get displayed.
Sleep | 2
Choose File | name=upload[] | C:\ScriptImages\Images\Injection-icon.png (file path)
Sleep | 2

Script fails and generates following error message :

"FAIL   ERROR: Command execution failure. Please search the user group at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-users for error details from the log window. The error message is: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable."